# Hey! My USDT was withdrawn from my Trust Wallet without my authorizing it. I did a test on Crypto.com Wallet, same thing my USDT was withdrawn

Tags: mining, addresses, mining-pools, usdt, trustwallet

Looks like another contract has appeared.
Transaction Hash:
https://bscscan.com/tx/0x5ca358080d6c762174a296998efef393d81fbcfa7f4421febe0cac3e197483df

Comment: Same happened to me bscmining it's scam I searched on Google when they ask for mining they used smart contract call